# AS3 - Open url bookmark from flash file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a flash file which is basically an animated TV that flicks through designs in my portfolio.  I have a button on the TV that when clicked should open a url in the current window.

The url is a link to my portfolio page, but as its a vertical scrolling site the url is a boomark #portfolio, can anyone recommend the best way to trigger this link within the smae window?

Thanks for your help
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear from the description whether you want to navigate from a flash to a html page.

- From flash to html the following will do fine:

  navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourpage.html#portfolio"));
- If you want to navigate within a swf file you will want to go for some deeplinking.
  Check out this [library](http://www.asual.com/swfaddress/) which will enable you to this in an easy way

Cheers